# How implement a transactions to cashbox report system in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
# Cash Testing Models
class Balance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = '8. Balance'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.amount)
    
    #def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        #cashsystem = Cashsystem.objects.filter(amount=self.balance.amount).order_by('-id').first()
        

  

class Income(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    details = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    income_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = '9. Income'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        cashsystem = Cashsystem.objects.filter(amount=self.balance.amount).order_by('-id').first()
        if cashsystem:
            ending_cash= cashsystem.amount + self.amount
            cashsystem.save()
        else:
            Cashsystem.objects.create(
                amount=self.balance.amount,
                income=self,
                expenses=None,
                income_amount=self.amount,
                expenses_amount=None,
                ending_cash=self.amount,
            )
        




class Expenses(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    details = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    expenses_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = '10. Expenses'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        cashsystem = Cashsystem.objects.filter(amount=self.balance.amount).order_by('-id').first()
        if cashsystem:
            ending_cash=cashsystem.amount - self.amount
            cashsystem.save()
        else:
            Cashsystem.objects.create(
                amount=self.balance.amount,
                income=None,
                expenses=self,
                income_amount=None,
                expenses_amount=self.amount,
                ending_cash=self.amount,
            )
        #super().save(*args, **kwargs)


# cash Model Testing
class Cashsystem(models.Model):
    #date=models.DateTimeField(default=Cash.objects.date())  # add default value here
    amount = models.ForeignKey(Balance, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=Balance.objects.first())
    income = models.ForeignKey(Income, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, null=True)
    expenses = models.ForeignKey(Expenses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, null=True)
    income_amount= models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    expenses_amount= models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    ending_cash = models.FloatField()




    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cash Box Entries'
        #ordering = ('-income__income_date', '-expenses__expenses_date')
    def income_date(self):
        if self.income:
            return self.income.income_date
        
    def expenses_date(self):`your text`
        if self.expenses:
            return self.expenses.expenses_date
```

I am building a personal Cash box management system, That will store My opening balance to Cashsystem and transactions like(income, expenses) will effect to my opening balance and show ending_cash( how much amount I still have in my cashsystem). I had make changes in condition many time and tried but didn't get perfect solution. I am beginner . please see my model if anything wrong in this model give me a solutions